# Як правильно ставити наголос в прізвищі Бойчук і чи впливає на це історичне походження прізвища?

Tags: власні-назви, наголос

Цікавить конкретно випадок з прізвищем *Бойчук* (хоча думаю, що є ще багато схожих спірних прізвищ): історично воно, як і декілька інших, походить від назви етнографічної групи [бо́йків](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8) (наголос на перший склад).

Прізвище *Бо́йко* (наголос на перший склад) зазвичай не має проблем з правильною вимовою, тоді як *Бойчук* на території, близькій до історичної батьківщини бойків, зазвичай вимовляється з наголосом на перший склад, поза межами неї — з наголосом на другий склад.

**Оновлення**
Змінив заголовок для кращого відображення суті запитання.

Comment: Це не відповідь і не обов'язково правда, але я щойно випадково знайшов оце: http://litmisto.org.ua/?p=22182.

Comment: Іще: я знаю, що в польській мові наголос *завжди* падає на передостанній склад, причому, відповідно, «скаче» при відмінюванні: Пілсу́дський — Пілсудсько́го (але я я не знаю, яке відношення поляки мають до бойків і чи міг хоча б теоретично бути якийсь зв'язок чи вплив).

Comment: @Sasha, а мене зацікавив наголос у прізвищах на *-ко*. Хотіла оформити як питання, а побачила схоже від Liberus, тепер вагаюся (ніби заголовок загальний, а в тексті - специфікація щодо одного прізвища). Знайшла дослідження [НАГОЛОШЕННЯ ПРІЗВИЩ НА -КО В МИНУЛОМУ І ТЕПЕР](http://kulturamovy.univ.kiev.ua/KM/pdfs/Magazine35-12.pdf) професора [Скляренка В.Г.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%92%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87). Думаю, цьому фахівцю можна довіряти. Що порадите?

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, так, давно помітив, що тут заголовок широкий, а питання про Бойчук. Мені здається наголос в українських прізвищах уцілому — надто широко. Я б: (1) Про -ко створив окреме питання. (2) Можливо, варто попросити автора звузити це.

Comment: [Редько Юліан Костянтинович](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE_%D0%AE%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87) У 1950-х почав збір даних про українські прізвища. В році в Академії наук Української РСР захистив докторську дисертацію «Сучасні українські прізвища (походження, словотвір, територіальне поширення)». Link @Sasha напевно звідси: "Редько Ю. К. Довідник українських прізвищ / За редакцією кандидата філологічних наук Івана Варченка. Київ, 1968." Ще: http://storinka-m.kiev.ua/article.php?id=1340

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Правило наголосу в українських прізвищах**

Українські прізвища передаються на письмі відповідно до вимови.

> 1. Прізвища, утворені від загальних назв, зберігають наголос загальної
>    назви.
> 2. Наголос на останньому складі мають прізвища з суфіксами **-ак(-як)**:
>    Грабчак, Бариляк, Настасяк, Остап’як, Романчак, Савчак; **-ук(-юк), -чук**: Захарук,
>    Бойчук, Біланчук, Шестопалюк. [Довідник українських прізвищ. Ю.К. Редько](http://http:/litmisto.org.ua/?p=22182)

[Прізвища іменникового типу](https://udhtu.edu.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/b7ae096b1e5cedc59c9371524703b474.pdf) відмінюються за зразком іменників відповідної відміни і групи (І, ІІ, ІІІ відміни; тверда, м’яка, мішана групи). До цієї групи належать прізвища, що походять від імен та загальних назв без зміни їх форми (Комашка, Галушка, Кочерга, Вітер, Лях, Журавель, Куліш), а також прізвища з суфіксами -ак, (-як), -ань, -ар, -ач, -евич, -ейко, -ець, -ник, -чук, -унь, -ун, -ик, -ич, -чак, -еня, -єня та ін. (Савченко, Коваленко, Масич, Ситар, Щербак, Лизун, Скрипник, Романюк, Вовчук, Зубеня, Сергієня) іпрізвища, утворені складанням основ різних частин мови (Рябошапка, Заплюйсвічка, Лизогуб, Підкуймуха, Тягнирядно, Держибаба, Живодер, Стрижикурка).

**Граматичні особливості, притаманні українським прізвищам**

> Також слід додати, що суфікси -енко, -єнко й -ук, -юк, є рівноважними,
> бо чергування звуків утворилось через різні закінчення основ, до яких
> приєднувався суфікс. Наприклад: Петро — Петренко, Петрик — Петриченко,
> Гордій — Гордієнко, Михайло — Михайлюк (заради милозвучності частіше
> використовується суфікс -юк, а не -ук), Бойко — Бойчук.
>
> Але в народній мові ці суфікси згодом набули рівного значення, тому
> прізвища, які утворились від одного імені, зустрічаються в різних
> варіантах, наприклад: Денисенко (Денис + енк + о), Денищенко (Дениско + енк + о), Романюк (Роман + юк), Романчук (Романко + ук). Тут маємо справу з чергуванням приголосних. Іноді помилково розглядаються
> суфікси -ченко/щенко та -чук/щук. Справа в тім, що патронімічні
> маркери -чук та -ченко утворюються від основ, що закінчуються на -ко:
> Федько, Василько, Іванко; а патронімічні маркери -щенко та -щук
> утворюються внаслідок чергування приголосних в основах, які
> закінчуються на -ско: Дениско, Бориско, Фесько. [wiki](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

За моїми суто суб'єктивними спостереженнями, прізвища з закінченнями -ук (-юк) в усному мовленні завжди наголошуються на цей останній склад, незалежно від етимології кореня. Втім, нічого не можу сказати щодо того, як наголошують такі прізвища на Бойківщині.

Comment: власне невпевнений що тут є правила специфічні до цієї етнічної групи, думаю схожі спірні ситуації є і з іншими прізвищами, просто вони мені не відомі

Comment: -1: це більше схоже на коментар, ніж на відповідь на запитання.

Answer (score 0):

Взагалі-то, на Франківщині наголошують букву о, тобто кажуть Бо́йчук (живу там і маю знайомих з таким прізвищем). Але насправді в українській мові не має ніяких правил з наголосами, щоб там не говорили ті мовознавці. У мене знайомі мають прізвища, як Ко́зак, так і Коза́к. А у моїй родині зустрічаються Савчу́к, Перегі́нчук, Біла́нчук. 
Думаю, варто в українській мові, враховуючи цю нестійкість, ввести обов'язкове наголошування на письмі і поступово наведеться лад з наголосам, а не каверзувати, що тоді текст важко сприйматиметься. Наприклад, у грецькій мові наголоси обов'язкові у словах, бо також плавають як в українській.

Comment: *«немає ніяких правил з наголосами»* — це занадто сильне твердження, якщо воно не підкріплене посиланнями на поважні джерела.

Comment: Sasha під моїм запитанням вказав посилання на джерело яке говорить про певні правила - але не особливо зрозуміло чи вони були виведені автором емпірично чи ні. Продовжую шукати щось на цю тему